# what's wrong with dynamic matchers on rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an attribute which name is alias and method which **create_alias**.I use create_alias method as before_validation callback.In the method decleration I have following lines

```
while ProjectType.find_by_alias(tmp) != nil 
  tmp = self.alias + "-" + i.to_s
  i += 1 
end
```

As you can see, the code tries to create unique alias but on rails 4.0 we encounter this error message.

```
SyntaxError: /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@comRails4/bundler/gems/rails-39555a5b1989/activerecord/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:65: syntax error, unexpected keyword_alias, expecting ')'
     def self.find_by_alias(alias, options = {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your column name. As you see, `alias` is Ruby keyword and it shouldn't be used as column name.